# how to change a drupal views output

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I need to create a block with eg the latest comments on the site.
when using views, concegui select the data I wanted, but the problem is that I need to edit the output of view (specify the html). I tried to make a tpl, but the fields when they get to this, are already formatted ([#markup]). also tried to make a block programmatically by accessing the fields of view, via `$comments = views_get_view('last_opinions');`, but so the fields do not bring content, but for example, ids (for referrals), or integers (in the case of dates), ....

basically, how to change views output?

Comment: Are you Using devel themer ?

Comment: yes, for discovery the name for tpl

Comment: Then you should not get problem with inserting your own DIV at the place where it's getting generated...

Answer (score 0):

views->your view->advance(third panel)-> Theme: Information -> click Information ->choose tpl as per your requirement and find $row which actually prints your output

Comment: thanks for the reply. As I understand from your answer, that would create a tpl for each of the fields for the row and the row style, because I want to modify almost everything. is not there a better way